# I have formatted an external HD in ext4. But now I want all my linux PCs to be able access it

Tags: partitioning, permissions, external-hdd

I am using Xubuntu 14.04 AMD64.

I just bought an external HD. I have wiped everything in it and formatted to ext4 the whole disk.

Now the only owner is root, I cannot create folders or copy contents on it. But I want all my linux boxes, (some of them not with the same user name I have in the computer that formatted the HDD, as I sometimes use my brother's computer or some other computer) to be able to access and create / delete contents on it.

How do I change permission access on the DH to allow any of my linux computers to delete and create contents of this new HD?

This disk appears as sdc.

Thanks

Alex

Comment: newly created ext4 partition should behave like this.

Comment: How do I change permission access on the DH to allow any of my linux computers to delete and create contents of this new HD?

Comment: change the permissions on the directory on which that ext4 partition is mounted.(`sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/mountpoint`)

Answer (score 0):

use samba that what i use then give permission to how ever on then hard drive also use mount go to discs on Ubuntu then click setting then click the mount setting then mount it automatically on start up